# Django: override the save() function of an abstract model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have tried to override the save() function on a model that is abstract, and am getting an error

```
Manager isn't accessible via Entry instances
```

So if possible, how do you override the save function on an abstract model. The model that extends from this is `Entry`

Here is my model Code:

```
class EntryBlog(EntryAbstractClass):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(group, null=True, blank=True)    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.featured:
            self.__class__().objects.all().update(featured = False)
        super(EntryBlog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

(For those who are familiar, I am extending the `Entry` model on the zinnia-blog, but dont think that is relevant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.__class__().objects` should be `self.__class__.objects`.

See the *Notes* on retrieving objects: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects

> Managers are accessible only via model classes, rather than from model instances, to enforce a separation between "table-level" operations and "record-level" operations.

Comment: `self.__class__.objects` or `EntryBlog.objects`, whichever looks cleaner to you.

Comment: I couldnt use `EntryBlog.objects` as it is abstract and struggles when trying to update. self.__class__ worked like a charm. As always, thanks!